# Rolling back a migration in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on my first ruby on rails project, and have created a "Users" table for my app using a "rails generate scaffold users" command.

Now I am trying to undo this statement as I wish to try to rewrite the classes involved with that class and table in my database.

I saw that the scaffold statement created a "def change" class in a migration, and when I try to rollback that migration there is no function within the migration.  I added a "def down" method with only the "drop_table :users" defined within it.

```
def down
    drop_table :users
end
```

However, when I run "rake db:rollback", there is no response in the command prompt and the table is unchanged.

I am not quite sure how to undo this migration to rewrite the table schema.  Can anyone offer assistance please?

The whole migration looks like the following:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string :name
            t.string :password_digest
            t.string :email

            t.timestamps
        end
    end

    def down
        drop_table :users
    end
end
```

EDIT:
Fixed this by running db:drop and db:rollback to clear my schema.  I think there was an issue with me having the database open in another program.  I closed it and that allowed the database to be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

`rails generate scaffold users` doesn't change your database, it only generate MVC code. You can simply undo it by `destroy scaffold` command

```
 rails destroy scaffold users
```

If you run `rake db:migrate` command than you can rollback it by rake `db:rollback` command. At migration file, `change` method is enough for create or drop operation of tables. No `down` method is needed, `down` method is the complement method of `up` method.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.  I did actually migrate the users table initially before trying to rollback these changes.  I've also destroyed the scaffold as well.  I opened up the Sqlite3 database and see that my old table is still there.  I went into my migration and also changed the "change" method to "up", and left the "down" method as it was.  I still am unable to get "rake db:rollback" to work.